# C++ SSE: Undefined behavior after storing to an array

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I am reading `uint64_t` integers from 2 unaligned vectors `vec1` and `vec2`, using the SSE instruction `_mm_loadu_si128` which reads data from both aligned and unaligned memory. I then do a bitwise and operation and then store the result using `_mm_storeu_si128` which stores data to an unaligned memory. The target of the store is an array called `arr1`. It seems that before the store, I can access `arr1`, but after the store accessing `arr1` gives an undefined behavior (sometimes segfaults).

```
#include <vector>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

        std::vector<uint64_t> vec1(200);
        std::vector<uint64_t> vec2(200,1);
        std::vector<uint64_t> *p_vec1 = &vec1;
        std::vector<uint64_t> *p_vec2 = &vec2;

        int total_bits = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for(; k < 100; k+=2){
                __m128i* ptr1 = (__m128i*) (p_vec1 + k);
                __m128i* ptr2 = (__m128i*) (p_vec2 + k);
                __m128i val1_4 = _mm_loadu_si128(ptr1);
                __m128i val2_4 = _mm_loadu_si128(ptr2);
                uint64_t arr1[2] = {0,0};
                 std::cout << "val1 " << arr1[0] << std::endl;
                _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) arr1, _mm_and_si128(val1_4, val2_4)); // after storing into arr1, Accessing arr1 gives undefined behavior
                std::cout << "val2 " << arr1[0] << std::endl; // This should only output 0s but instead outputs random numbers
                total_bits += __builtin_popcountll(arr1[0]);
         }
}
```

Is `_mm_storeu_si128` "changing the structure" of `arr1`, is that why I can't access it after the store?

Comment: `&vec1` gives you the address of the `vector` object itself, not the objects stored in the vector. You might try `uint64_t* ptr = &vec1[0]` instead, to get the address of the first value stored.

Comment: `uint64_t* ptr = vec1.data()` looks a bit more readable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<uint64_t> *p_vec1 = &vec1;
std::vector<uint64_t> *p_vec2 = &vec2;
```

is most definitely not what you want. It doesn't mean `p_vec1` is pointing to elements in the vector, its pointing to the vector itselft. You later do `(__m128i*) (p_vec1 + k)` which reading from is undefined behavior: `p_vec1 + 1` isn't pointing to the second value of the vector; it's pointing to the vector after `vec1` (which doesn't make any sense).

You'd probably want something along the lines of:

```
uint64_t *p_vec1 = vec1.data();
uint64_t *p_vec2 = vec2.data();
```

so that `p_vec1` and `p_vec2` are pointing to the contents of the vector.